# How to remove the focus border on hyperlink in Typescript

Tags: typescript, hyperlink, focus

I write the code in typescript

*`"<a onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;\" href=\"https://support.office.com/client/61994a3b-2c87-41c4-a88d-a6455efa362d?omkt=en-US\" >license terms</a>"`,

`"<a onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;\" href=\"https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement\">privacy policy</a>")`;*

And when run the ts code, it shows like below with an unexpected focus box on the first hyperlink. How can I remove it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change style with `active` and `focus` pseudo-selector.
Unluckily, you can't change pseudo-selector styles with inline style.
So you should do it throug CSS or JS.

**CSS version**:
TS file:

```
<a 
    onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;\" 
    href=\"https://support.office.com/client/61994a3b-2c87-41c4-a88d-a6455efa362d?omkt=en-US\" 
    class="my-class">
    license terms
</a>
```

CSS file:

```
my-class:active, my-class:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

**JS version:**

```
<a 
    onclick=doSomething(e)
    href=\"https://support.office.com/client/61994a3b-2c87-41c4-a88d-a6455efa362d?omkt=en-US\" 
    class="my-class">
    license terms
</a>

const doSomething = (e) => {
    e.target.style.outline = "none";
    e.target.style.border = "none";
    window.open(this.href,'_blank');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I find it is because in the code base they require focus when htmlinstance, I try to skip the code and my issue is fixed.
if (item instanceof HTMLElement) {
window.focus();
item.focus();